# Dataframe from nested lists

Tags: r, list, dataframe, nested

I have a list "fieldInfo" that contains nested lists and lists inside the nested lists. Below you can see its structure: Any ideas how to create a data frame that makes sense out of it? Im open to suggestions. I used jsonlite to extract data .Thanks in advance.

```
$id
[1] "9EB98349-B021-1ACC-892D-DF657D147D58"

$parent_id
[1] "245A310E-0DA9-40F8-90D2-F073FF6E7F42"

$field_id
[1] "9EB98349-B021-1ACC-892D-DF657D147D58"

$field_number
[1] 19

$field_label
[1] "Vind je dit CRF leuk?"

$field_is_alias
[1] FALSE

$field_variable_name
[1] "crf_leuk"

$field_type
[1] "radio"

$field_required
[1] 1

$field_hidden
[1] 0

$field_info
[1] ""

$field_units
[1] ""

$field_min
NULL

$field_min_label
NULL

$field_max
NULL

$field_max_label
NULL

$field_summary_template
NULL

$field_slider_step
NULL

$report_id
[1] ""

$field_length
NULL

$additional_config
NULL

$exclude_on_data_export
[1] FALSE

$option_group
$option_group$id
[1] "32C13510-A9EF-BB86-5439-6E70607BD549"

$option_group$name
[1] "4pts Leuk Schaal"

$option_group$description
[1] "Ja een vierpuntsschaal"

$option_group$layout
[1] FALSE

$option_group$options
                                    id               name value groupOrder
1 E4B1A938-EBE0-207E-9D91-B6C7BAD0C130 Helemaal niet leuk     1          0
2 7DF7D17C-A0B2-6DCF-33CB-C5C8E9EC7CFF       Niet zo leuk     2          1
3 478CF871-3F29-E3EA-A29B-39DEF8F3C440      Heel erg leuk     3          2
4 6C98B92E-7E26-AD91-0D6A-3E2757B4A124 Heel heel erg leuk     5          3
5 C8FD2291-42AB-4A1F-C520-E4FB46A2EE55     Not applicable    NA          4

$option_group$fields
list()


$metadata_points
list()

$validations
list()

$dependency_parents
list()

$dependency_children
list()

$`_links`
$`_links`$self
$`_links`$self$href
[1] "https://rc.do.castoredc.com/api/study/50F73B74-8706-4A9E-AED9-9582BAED9D42/field/9EB98349-B021-1ACC-892D-DF657D147D58"
```

Comment: A list structure seems much better suited for this data than a rectangular data.frame. Why do you want to convert it anyway?

Comment: In order to apply analysis and data visualization easily when transform it.

Comment: It has to be combined later with other lists to create the data frame totally but i want to start with this